# Value of '10000' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'. Parameter name: Value

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Value of '345900' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Parameter name: Value

```
 if (e.CurrentProgress > 0)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CurrentProgress);
            progressBar1.Maximum = (100);
            progressBar1.Minimum = (0);

        }
        else
            progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(0);
```

update:
appreciate everyone for helping me.. i found the solution though it is not the complete solution anyways.. here is the code.

```
 if ((e.CurrentProgress > 0) && (e.MaximumProgress > 0))
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(e.MaximumProgress);
            progressBar1.Step = Convert.ToInt32(e.CurrentProgress);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            progressBar1.Refresh();
        }
            else
                progressBar1.Value = (0);
```

Comment: You're setting the maximum value to 100, but trying to set the value to 1000.

Comment: Common man, you set maximum to 100 and expect it to accept 10000 as value?

Comment: What specifically isn't clear from the exception message? All anyone can do is read the message back to you. It's not clear what you expect from users on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** I'm not sure if the answer below made sense before the question was edited. But it definitely looks pointless after :-).

---

<s>It is a bit hard to say, but maybe swapping lines will help (and I guess there is no need for `unchecked`):</s>

```
progressBar1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(e.MaximumProgress);
progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CurrentProgress);
```

Comment: it is not working.. swapping lines makes no change in my error

Comment: Are you sure that `e.MaximumProgress >= e.CurrentProgress`?

Comment: the error occurs exactly at this point.  progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CurrentProgress);

Comment: Sure. What is the value of `e.MaximumProgress` at this moment?

Comment: im not sure if the maximum progress is greater than current progress because the current progress is dynamic, it takes values on loading webpages only. i dont fix that current progress.

Comment: the value of maximum progress at the moment is 100

Comment: hey AlexD, i think you could help out. can i chat with you.. i just need to show some pictures of my code and exactly where iam suffering with. if its not too personal, i want to talk to you.

Comment: `ProgressBar` has `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Value`. And the `Value` must be in between. So if you are trying to set `Value` outside of the range, you get the exception. If `e.CurrentProgress` exceed `e.MaximumProgress`, it might be an error within the class which triggers the event. I hardly see how I can help here :).

Comment: Value of '345900' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Parameter name: Value when i load google home page this error is displayed to me..